# texture mapping menu missing in blender render 2.75

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

[image: this]

I cant find the texture mapping drop down menu in the texture menu when using blender render, are there any alternatives?

[image]

Comment: You're right, the Mapping panel should be there. Can you post the blend file please?

Answer (score 3):

This is because *Use Nodes* is enabled on the material using the texture:

[image]

Once this option is disabled, the *Mapping* panel is available in the texture options.