# Cannot access mapping section of the texture tab

Tags: texturing, interface

I am following a blender tutorial and on the tutorial, the guy is able to access a section of the textures tab called Mapping and Influence but I am not able to see that anywhere on mine.

Mine is on the left, his is on the right:

[image] [image]

How do I access the mapping section on blender 2.75

Thanks!

Comment: Slightly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34993/599

Comment: My guess is that you have Cycles on as the render engine. AFAIK. the Influence tab is available only in the Internal Render engine. Have a look in the very upper bar in Blender to the left of the version info. Also, try setting the texture type to image and loading an image.